# logging not happening?

Tags: logging, log4j

I'm using struts1.3.8 and for logging, log4j using. It is writing logs in Windows but not on Unix..
After analyzed,I came to know there are commons-logging and log4j jars are in lib. I think clash happened.when i removed commons-logging and executed it throwed `ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`
   i'm using log4j.properties file for appenders and location of writing logs. 
I tried with commons-logging by removing log4j by this time how to configure the properties?

My code is

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO,CA, FA

#Console Appender
log4j.appender.CA = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern =  %d  %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#File Appender
log4j.appender.FA = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FA.File =/usr/mylogs.log
log4j.appender.FA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d  %5p [%t] - %m%n
```

Any idea is appreciatable.

Laxman chowdary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the problem with access permissions.. Not having write permissions to create and write to file.

Answer (score 0):

If logging is working on windows and not on unix means may be problem with path specified in log4j properties file. make sure the path in log4j properties is fine and file separator should be '/'.

Comment: check whether you have permission to /usr dir, if so give different path